# Unable to create projects in Rider

Tags: c#, msbuild, rider

Recently downloaded Rider and I'm unable to create projects. It either hangs infinitely on "Creating solution file" or gives me the following error :

> Unable to load project and obtain project information from MsBuild.
> Try to change MsBuild version in 'Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Toolset and Build'.
> Probably this project is incompatible with the current MsBuild.
> MsBuild error details:
> 1 is not a supported code page.

I tried changing the MsBuild path, adding Msbuild to environment variables, installing mono and reinstalling the Rider but none of these worked. I have Visual Studio installed(which works) so I shouldn't be encountering such problems, according to [this](https://rider-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207288089-Using-Rider-under-Windows-without-Visual-Studio-prerequisites) . Any help is appreciated.I'm on windows 10 if that helps.

Comment: Have you search if there are tickets posted on Rider support with the same *or similar issue* you described? - as I read your question, it *might* be something with the installation of Rider in your PC.

Comment: It can be diagnosed with logs. I would recommend to call Help - Report a Bug, agree to attach logs.

Comment: Probably Rider tries to use broken installation of .NET Core. Try to change msbuild in Toolset and Build settings page

Answer (score 0):

You should re-install dotnet, in your OS. See [this documentation page](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33051523)